# Find the slope for 2 known variables?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Couldn't find anything really useful for my needs. So if I already know my 2 variables x(Rise) and y(Run), and I want the slope in degrees, what is the best way to go about coding this? And how would you format a textfield for the answer?

Comment: Probably really a question for mathoverflow... Not sure what rise and run are in your case. However, what you want are the trigonometric functions, i.e sine, cosine and in your case tangens.

Comment: @mrueg: I'm pretty certain it's not a question for mathoverflow at all. Perhaps math.stackexchange.com at best, but I'm not sure how strict they are with regards to triviality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simplest is just to use

```
double slope = atan2(rise, run)*180/M_PI_2;
```

Comment: I think you mean something like `double slope = atan2(...`, and `M_PI`, not `M_PI_2` (which is Pi/2). Just as a comment, `atan2(rise, run)` already computes the desired angle in _radians_, multiplying by 180°/Pi gives you the expression in _degrees_. Finally, we usually would say _x_ is the run and _y_ is the rise, on a standard (_x_, _y_)-coordinate system. Just convention (though it's good to follow common use), just make sure to get it right.

Comment: do `textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", slope];` where `slope = atan2(rise, run) * 180 / M_PI;`. I think it is `M_PI` and not `M_PI_2` as suggested by @Eytan

Comment: And this is the degrees right? I did use `double slope = atan2(Rise, Run)*180/M_PI;`